# How to change multiclass labels to binary labels in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, multiclass-classification

I have a dataset that is labeled with the classes 0-3 and I'm trying to change it so that I can run my classifier with binary labels. So I want to change classes 2 and 3 to class 1. Is there a quick way to do it?
Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have a column that contains 3 types, so below code simply do the task;

```
df['column'] = df['column'].map({'first_element':1, 'second_element':2,'third_element':3})
```

Comment: Are 'first_element', 'second_element' and 'third_element' the original classes? So '2':1, '3':1 ?

Comment: yes, if you want to change to str or any other type use .astype() , for conversion it'll be like df['column] = df['column'].astype(str)
It'll be easier to understand if you can show a sample of your dataset

Answer (score 0):

```
df['column'] = np.where(df.column == "class0", "class0", "class1")
```

This will effectively leave class0 to class0 only but the remaining classes will be labeled class1.